# Dynamic get id of element

Tags: android, android-layout

I have simple layout called `item` which is
`linearlayout` with elements `textView` and twice `imageButton`

Then, I use this layout to generate list (inflate it 10 times).
I can't set the same ID on more than one element, so I do not set any.

In each layout `item` I can click, on

- linearlayout
- first imageButton
- second imageButton

**How to know, which linearlayout, imagebutton was clicked?**

Comment: well you should probably use a recycler or list view :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't set the same ID

Yes, you can't. But you can generate one using [`generateViewId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html):

From docs:

> Generate a value suitable for use in setId(int). This value will not collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for R.id.

```
view.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

And than you can exactly refer to your view.

But this shouldn't be a solution that you should consider to stick with. Instead you should prefer to delegate those logics to `RecyclerView`.